# How do I spawn fused TNT at a players location through the console?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Wanna troll a friend on minecraft I couldn't find anything on the internet so I went here

Comment: You weren't able to find anything on the internet? What did you try? It's extremely easy (but not nice), so if you properly searched, you should have found something.

Answer (score 2):

You will use the [execute command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute) which will cause the command to run as though your friend is the one that executed it.  With this, you will execute a [summon command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#summon) to produce the tnt at the player's feet.

```
execute <entity> ~ ~ ~ summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:80}
```

Replace `<entity>` with the player's name.

If you want the tnt to detonate immediately, remove `{Fuse:80}` from the command.  This specifies the number of ticks of delay before the tnt detonates.  In this case, 80 ticks is about 4 seconds, which is the same delay that striking tnt with flint and steel has.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute at <entity> run summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:80}`

Answer (score 1):

In **1.18.2**:

```
/execute at ExamplePlayer run summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse: 1}
```

The `~ ~ ~` is relative `(X Y Z)` coordinates to the player you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by entering this command:

```
summon PrimedTnt ~ ~1 ~ {Fuse:80}
```

https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/349889-spawn-lit-tnt-with-command-block

Comment: PrimedTnt is no longer a valid [entity ID](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Java_Edition_data_values/Entity_IDs).  This command will fail to execute.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated and More Detailed Answer For 1.18.2+

---

If you want to summon a fused TNT block, then you will need to use the `/execute` command to do so. You can do this by using this format:

```
execute at <entity> run summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~ ~ {fuse:80}
```

Let's break this command down a little bit:

## `execute`

This command is used to actually summon the fused TNT *at* the player. Just using:

```
summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~ ~ {fuse:80}`
```

...will fail to execute inside of a command block because it needs a target, so that is where the `execute` command comes in: it gives it a specific target.

## `~ ~ ~`

This basically tells Minecraft where the TNT will be summoned in the `xyz` format. In the Minecraft commands syntax, `~` means where the exact target's position is.

### A cool tip to remember...

You can add *integers* next to the `~`s to either add or subtract from a player's position.

Example:

```
summon minecraft:tnt ~1 ~-3 ~2 {fuse:320}
```

(This will summon a fused TNT block that has a 16 second delay, is summoned 1 block to the right, 3 blocks below the *player's head* and 2 blocks ahead. ***Note that this example can only be used in the console, NOT a command block***.)

## `{fuse:<int>}`

This adds a delay in *Minecraft ticks* to determine how long the fused TNT in question will blow up. Thanks to the ***amazing*** way NBT data works in the Java Edition of Minecraft, this part is customizable (again, remember that this is determined in **Minecraft ticks**).

In this example:

```
execute at <entity> run summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~ ~ {fuse:160}
```

This will tell Minecraft to wait for 8 seconds until it blows up. (***An easy
way to determine how many real time seconds it will take for TNT to blow up is with this equation:***)

```
t = ticks
t/20 = real time seconds
```