# What is the command to summon an ignited TNT block as of 1.20.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

One day I was watching YouTube, and decided to watch Technoblade (RIP, dude...), and I was watching the video where TNT is summoned every 10 seconds (video shown below).

I wanted to recreate that challenge and tried this command:

```
/summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~ ~
```

...but it just summons a TNT explosion animation when it blows up. I couldn't find anything else in Minecraft or on the internet. ***What is the command for summoning an ignited TNT block as of 1.20.4?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can delay the explosion by adding the `fuse` tag:

```
/summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {fuse:80}
```

This command will summon a lit tnt block that explodes after 4 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

To summon a TNT block through a command you can use (as [Semlan Bakelsen suggested](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/405933/163757)) the following:

```
/summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~ ~ {fuse:1}
```

As mentioned in [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/333475/how-do-i-spawn-fused-tnt-at-a-players-location-through-the-console) post you can use the execute command to summon a primed TNT at the player's feet:

```
/execute at <entity> run summon minecraft:tnt ~ ~ ~ {fuse:80}
```

You can use [this](https://www.gamergeeks.net/apps/minecraft/summon/tnt) website to create your own custom commands for different Minecraft versions.

I also found [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/how-to-spawn-tnt-on-location-every-10-seconds.501346/) thread on spigotmc with code snippets should you wish to dabble with that.

I haven't played Minecraft in quite some time but you could use a [repeating command block](https://minecraft-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Repeating_Command_Block#:%7E:text=To%20get%20a%20repeating%20command,in%20the%20command%20block%20GUI.) to repeat the above mentioned commands every X time.